# Как с помощью регулярного выражения матчить паттерн строки, если он встречается не более одного раза?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Сами строки состоят из n цифр, пробела, n букв

```
<p>1 test</p>
<p>222 test</p>
<p>333 test</p>
```

Матчится строка должна, если она встречается не более одного раза
Моя регулярка матчит все строки:

```regex
(<p>\d*\s\w*</p>)(?!<p>\d*\s\w*</p>){1,}
```

https://regex101.com/r/fudrtm/1

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а где регулярка?

Comment: @Эникейщик ссылка

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ок, сорян

Answer (score -1):

Ну Вы и намудрили.

`(?<=<p>)(.*)(?=</p>)`

Создайте условие, которое проверяет количество найденных строк, если их больше одной, то идём дальше, если нет, то забираем одну.